# How do i change the color of a store header if not the main store using js and xml?

Tags: javascript, xml

```
            initStore: function (store) {//setupStoreUI
            if (store !== 'MAIN') {
                var padding = "";
                var bg = "background-image: url(img/stores/" + store.toLowerCase() + "-logo.svg);";
                $logo[0].style = bg + padding;
                        
            }
```

XML

**<store mainColor="990000>**

Comment: JavaScript doesn't know anything about stores, it sounds like you're using a library of some kind. You need to provide details so people familiar with that library will see the question.

Comment: i never used xml before, but i did put a mainColor attribute in the stores.xml and i tried  calling "document.documentElement.style.setProperty" but that did not seem to work :(

Comment: What is stores.xml? JavaScript doesn't read XML files by default, it sounds like that's part of an e-commerce framework.

Comment: stores.xml is just data for the actual store whether it be; price, desc, mainColor, shipping etc... i already made the function using backbone.js everything is working fine but the header doesnt want to change color when i visit another part of the store. I have several stores that vary in color

Answer (score 0):

I'd be curious as to what the interface for `store` is. However, if the `mainColor` variable is available as a string on it, then you could do this:

```js
// get the header element
const header = document.querySelector(".header"); // or whatever selector it is
header.style = "background-color: " + store.mainColor;
```

Comment: store is pretty much the stores, we have a Main store that has a specific header color, but when you click on a different store the header changes color and I stored all the data in XML format so i can get the data. I tried inspecting it in the console and it shows up when i type "app.data.stores" i see mainColor so i know its working...

Comment: @Michael is the different store on a different website? and if its the same site, is there a callback in your framework to execute code on page navigate? or is the page refreshed?

Comment: @Michael also can you give the output of app.data.stores?

Comment: same site just a different path.